# React, No sourcemap for user codes in chrome performance tab,

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, create-react-app

I'm following a guide to [performance tuning](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/speed/get-started#main).

The problem I have is, I can't see the source codes in doing this.
I know the sourcemap is there.
If I go to `Sources` tab, I can see the `main.js` fine.

But the `Performances` tab can't recognize the sourcemap and all the lines are at `1` as in `main.57360ceb.chunk:1`.

I'm using `create-react-app` to build this project.

[image]

Comment: The file you circled isn't a map file, right? It's just a regular JS file. Map files have `.js.map` extension

Comment: It's the source file.. all other files have line numbers other than 1, this file is showing line number 1.. because all the contents are all in line 1

Comment: When you say "source file" generally that means the original, legible code that you wrote. That one is a transpiled chunk file, and will be unreadable. To get info from it you'll need its corresponding map file, e.g. `main.57360ceb.chunk.js.map`. CRA generates sourcemap files in production by default. Have you ejected the app? Or overidden `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP` environment variable anywhere?

Comment: No, I haven't ejected nor overriden GENERATE_SOURCEMAP, as I said in the op. I can see the original file and I see that as a proof that sourcemap is generated fine. But `performance` tab doens't see the original file..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something wrong with Chrome, I test in `Chrome 106.0.5249.119 stable` and sourcemap in `Performance` dose not work.

But it works well in `Chrome 109.0.5366.0 canary`.

[image]

Comment: Same issue when using Memory tab for heap profiling. Doesn't resolve sourcemaps on Chrome Beta (107) but works on Canary (109)

Comment: Update: it is flaky, sometimes it works, but most often it does not resolve sourcemap references. Please let me know if you find any fix.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) extension for Google Chrome. It will add Profiler and Components tab in your Chrome DevTools (F12). This extension is from Facebook.